# Reading streaming http response with Python "requests" library

Tags: python, stream, python-requests, kubernetes

I am trying to consume an event stream provided by the  [Kubernetes](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/kubernetes)
api using the `requests` module.  I have run into what looks like a
buffering problem: the `requests` module seems to lag by one event.

I have code that looks something like this:

```
r = requests.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1beta1/watch/services',
                 stream=True)

for line in r.iter_lines():
    print 'LINE:', line
```

As Kubernetes emits event notifications, this code will only display
the last event emitted when a new event comes in, which makes it
almost completely useless for code that needs to respond to service
add/delete events.

I have solved this by spawning `curl` in a subprocess instead of using
the `requests` library:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['curl', '-sfN',
                      'http://localhost:8080/api/watch/services'],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     bufsize=1)

for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print 'LINE:', line
```

This works, but at the expense of some flexibility.  Is there a way to
avoid this buffering problem with the `requests` library?

Answer (score 11):

This behavior is due to a buggy implementation of the `iter_lines`
method in the `requests` library.

`iter_lines` iterates over the response content in `chunk_size` blocks
of data using the `iter_content` iterator.  If there are less than
`chunk_size` bytes of data available for reading from the remote
server (which will typically be the case when reading the last line of
output), the read operation will block until `chunk_size` bytes of
data are available.

I have written my own `iter_lines` routine that operates correctly:

```
import os


def iter_lines(fd, chunk_size=1024):
    '''Iterates over the content of a file-like object line-by-line.'''

    pending = None

    while True:
        chunk = os.read(fd.fileno(), chunk_size)
        if not chunk:
            break

        if pending is not None:
            chunk = pending + chunk
            pending = None

        lines = chunk.splitlines()

        if lines and lines[-1]:
            pending = lines.pop()

        for line in lines:
            yield line

    if pending:
        yield(pending)
```

This works because `os.read` will return less than `chunk_size` bytes
of data rather than waiting for a buffer to fill.

Comment: It can be argued which implementation is correct - your one will insert a fake "logical line break" if more data becomes available. The correct approach appears to be to find out the total size of data (specifying one is a requirement for TCP communications) and only employ partial read at the known end.

Comment: I don't think you can argue that the existing implementation is correct.  Mine has not undergone under rigorous testing, but it certainly works better.  A more correct implementation -- ideally submitted as an upstream patch -- would be super useful.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev *"The correct approach appears to be to find out the total size of data (specifying one is a requirement for TCP communications)"* -- No, TCP is a *stream* and could have infinite length. I'm not sure where you heard that but it is fundamentally untrue.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart because of this, any TCP protocol worth its salt requires the sender to specify the length of each chunk of data it's going to send. That's what I meant by "requirement".

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev *"your one will insert a fake "logical line break" if more data becomes available"* - I don't think this is true. If this approach doesn't read all the way to a newline, it buffers the trailing content in `pending` until after reading the next chunk. I don't see a way this could have the effect of introducing an extra newline that wasn't really in the response; how do you figure that's possible?

Comment: That said, I think this *is* broken, just for the *opposite* reason to what @ivan_pozdeev suggests: it can *swallow* newlines. Note that unlike `.split('\n')`, trailing newlines are completely ignored by `.splitlines()`; that is, `'foo\nbar'.splitlines()` and `'foo\nbar\n'.splitlines()` give the same result, which is `['foo', 'bar']`. It thus seems to me (by inspection; haven't tested) that any time a chunk ends with a newline, you'll discard that trailing newline, store the last line in `pending`, and later yield the concatenation of it and the first line of the next chunk as a single line.

Comment: Sorry, but how could you apply your "iter_lines" to "requests"

Comment: Note that this answer is almost 10 years old, and I don't know if `requests` still has the same underlying problem. The `iter_lines` function presented here takes a file-like object, so you could pass it the `raw` attribute of a `requests` response object.